# How to rephrase "do not necessarily translate into"?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request, paraphrasing

I have to talk about a particular issue (small), but I can't seem to be able to hit the mark.

I need to paraphrase/rephrase this sentence:

> Higher unemployment rates do not necessarily **translate** into longer durations of unemployment. - Author (2011)

Here, "translate" means *"to decide that words, behaviour, or actions mean a particular thing"* (Cambridge).

This is my attempt at paraphrasing/rephrasing:

> Author (2011) argues that higher unemployment rates are not necessarily indicative of longer durations of unemployment.

Or

> Author (2011) argues that higher rates of unemployment do not necessarily suggest that workers will experience long spells of unemployment.

As you can see, it is rather a poor attempt to rephrase the original. I can't find a word that is close to "translate" with that particular meaning.

Comment: Actually _translate into_ also means _to result in_. See https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/translate, intransitive verb 3. Are you sure the one in your sentence is not used in this way?

Comment: Yes that's the same as meaning as the one I mentioned, just worded differently.

Comment: This site is not intended as a resource to learn how to cleverly plagiarize without being caught. But since you've cited your source, why bother paraphrasing in the first place? Simply provide the original wording within quotation marks. *Author (2011) argues that "higher unemployment rates do not necessarily translate into longer periods of unemployment."* If you want to paraphrase, especially *because* you've cited a source, you don't do so on a word-by-word basis. A paraphrase is a *general* restatement or summary; it's not exact. To be exact, simply quote.

Comment: @JasonBassford Hi Jason, it was not my intention at all to seek ways to cleverly plagiarize. The way I wrote the question might give that idea, I will edit my question/post so that is not in the discussion.

Comment: My advice is to avoid putting duration in the plural.

Comment: @AIQ I hadn't actually thought you were trying to plagiarize, just pointing out that it was an odd thing to ask. But, that aside, the rest of my comment stands. It should be quoted exactly (with quotes), or it should be paraphrased in a manner than is not just a word-for-word substitution. (But beyond that, if you remove everything about your question except for *What's the best synonym for **translate**?* that ends up being a matter of opinion or something that should be found in a thesaurus. Also, to find a *different* word, we normally need to know what's *wrong* with the original.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think your original attempts are that bad. They both preserve what is meant by the original sentence.

If you are looking for a phrase to replace *translate into*, check [the Merriam-Webster Thesaurus entry for translate (into)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/translate%20into).

If you are paraphrasing to avoid plagiarism, I'd suggest make more changes than only replacing *translate*, for example, you can reverse the sentence to say that B is not a necessary consequence of A.

Answer (score 0):

The word **interpret** can be used in place of *translate*.

**[Interpret](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/interpret)**: (Cambridge Dictionary)

> (Find meaning) to describe the meaning of
>   something; examine in order  to explain.

Or,

> (Change language) to change what someone is saying into the words of
>   another language; translate.